# Embed webrtc in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, webrtc

Is there a way that I can run webrtc video chat from within flex enviornment ?

I have a flex application, I want to add video chat to it and webrtc seems to be the way to go.

If I can somehow integrate webrtc in flex, it will solve my video chat problem .

Any idea how to if possibke ?

Comment: Are you using Air or flex?

Comment: You can build a bridge between flex and js by using ExternalInterface class. But I'm not sure that you can make it work with webrtc. I would suggest you to look in p2p in flash. You can use it for building video chats and it's quite easy to use. Maybe it could help http://www.jamesward.com/2010/12/06/p2p-in-desktop-mobile-and-tablet-flex-apps/